# How to perform ajax call on anchor tag

Tags: jquery, ajax

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#test').mouseover(function(){
          $('#test').ajaxForm({ 
            beforeSubmit: ShowRequest,
            success: SubmitSuccesful,
            error: AjaxError                               
          });                                    
       });    
       }); 
        function ShowRequest(formData, jqForm, options) {

        $("#loading").show();
        return true;
        }

        function AjaxError() {
        }

        function SubmitSuccesful(responseText, statusText) {  
  $(function() {
  var array=['ravi','abhi','raj','amol','neha','snehal','skksldfjsfsdfddsf','dkfks'];
    // add loading image to div
  $(function() {
    $("#test").attr('title',array.join('<br/>'));
    $("#test").tooltip({

        content:function(){return $(this).attr('title');},

   position: {
        my: "center bottom-20",
        at: "center top",
        using: function( position, feedback ) {
          $( this ).css( position );
          $( "<div>" )
            .addClass( "arrow" )
            .addClass( feedback.vertical )
            .addClass( feedback.horizontal )
            .appendTo( this );
        }
      }
   });  
});
});

 }    
  </script>

<div id="loading"></div>

<p>Ravi, Raj and <a href="#" id="test" title="enable to load">5 more</a></p>
```

it shows one error "Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method ajaxForm....
Please tell me what changes should needed... on success of ajax call list should be my list should be display....... is there any way to solve this??

Comment: .ajaxForm() istn a native jquery function, as long as you have no external js code that delivers that .ajaxForm() method, it will throw this error

Comment: Then what should I use?

Comment: you should do the same as where you copied that code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`.ajaxForm()` is not a native jquery function. You have to include external js library to use `.ajaxForm()`. And important thing is `.ajaxForm()` will work with html `form` elements. I dont see form in your html code. If you want to use ajax call for your anchor just use [.ajax()](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) native function in your `.mouseenter` function:

Sample:

```
$.ajax({
  url: "test.html",
  context: content
}).done(function() {
  // add code here to execute after ajax call
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Add this line to your head after `jquery.js`

```
<script src="http://malsup.github.com/jquery.form.js"></script>
```

[**Reference**](http://malsup.com/jquery/form/)